# Array with saving previous objects in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system, array

I need to make an array for iteration selected objs in future. But when I push needed element, it updates. It's because I always call a new var: `var objs = [];` How can I add the element right?

My code:

```
var objs = [];
objs.push(objs);
objs.push(event.getSource().get("v.name"));
component.set('v.objs', objs);
```

In cmp:

```
<aura:attribute name="objs" type="MyObject__c[]" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to start from your existing data rather than initializing an empty array.

```
var objs = component.get('v.objs');
objs.push(event.getSource().get("v.name"));
component.set('v.objs', objs);
```

Your current code will not accumulate objects because it always overwrites from a blank array plus the latest value.